# My gui is not printing the required username on clicking a button

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, kivy

I have created a gui which prints the text of username button being clicked..It is not printing anything.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class AllAccsPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AllAccsPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        usernames = self.grab_accounts()
        self.butt_height = 0.8
        for username in (usernames):
            self.username = username 
            self.acc_butt = Button(text=username, size_hint = (0.2, 0.1),
            pos_hint = {'x':0.1, 'y':self.butt_height}, background_color=(0,0,0,1))
            self.acc_butt.bind(on_click=self.save_info)
            self.add_widget(self.acc_butt)
            self.butt_height -= 0.1 
        

    def grab_accounts(self):
        my_f = open('usernames and passwords.txt', 'r')
        text = my_f.readlines()
        plain_text = [re.sub('\n','', line) for line in text]
        all_dict = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in plain_text]
        all_usernames = [each['username'] for each in all_dict]
        return all_usernames
    
    def save_info(self):
        print(self.username)

class DiaryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AllAccsPage
if name=='main'
    DiaryApp.run()
```

This isnt giving any error but isnt printing either

Comment: Try using `on_press` instead of `on_click`.

Comment: thanks @JohnAnderson it worked!!!